# Database design User Group Orders

Tags: database-design

I am making an application where an superuser can take orders from members and can create groups of multiple members which also can take orders.

Right now i have the following design:

Members

- id(pk)
- name
- isGroup

GroupMembers

- id(pk)
- GroupId = also the id of a member in members table
- memberId(Fk -> members.id)

Oders

- id
- memberid (Fk -> members.id)
- product id (Fk -> product.id)

Also thought about:

Members

- id(pk)
- name

Groups

- id(pk)
- name

GroupMembers

- id(pk)
- GroupId = (Fk -> Groups.id)
- memberId(Fk -> members.id)

Oders

- id
- memberid (Fk -> members.id) nullable
- Groupid (Fk -> members.id) nullable
- product id (Fk -> product.id)

Which design is better or is there a better design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual - it depends. If you're familiar with object oriented design, you may find it helpful to think of "members" and "groups" as objects. Is a group really a type of member (inheritance)? Is there a common super type for both members and groups? When you go further with the data model, will there be shared attributes between members and groups?

If "member" and "group" have nothing more in common than that they can both place orders, it's probably best to create separate tables (your second design).

If "member" and "group" are basically the same concept, you may want to try the following:

Entity
      ID 
      Name
      EntityTypeID

EntityType

```
  EntityTypeID
  Name ("group" or "member")
```

GroupMembers

```
ParentEntityId = (Fk -> entity.id)
ChildEntityId(Fk -> entity.id)
```

Orders

```
id
EntityID    
product id (Fk -> product.id)
```

Comment: The only thing they have in common is that they can place orders, members also get bank details, email etc. So its not a "bad" design to have groupId and MemberId in ther order table?